# Get notified when app runs into an infinite loop?

Tags: java, infinite-loop

We have our product built on Java stack, and its basically a transactional system. I am just curious to know that do we have any mechanism so that a notification can be sent if program goes into an infinite loop? Or may be we can kill the java process itself? or something better?

Comment: with the information given, no... see the halting problem.  for more specific cases, it's possible but you have to give implementation details.

Comment: Yeah, in general -- no.  Maybe use logs to see if it keeps trying to do the same thing over and over again?

Comment: If the infinite loop is part of your program that cannot be removed (a close example is a badly written regex on an input designed to slow down the regex engine - this is not inf. loop per se, but the very long execution time makes it a candidate to be stopped), then you may time out the execution after a threshold

Comment: @nhahtdh unless your example is written in an interrupt friendly manner there is no way to time out execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using JTA-transactions you can set a timeout for these on your application server. An exception will be thrown if a transaction takes to much time (for instance because of an infinite loop, but also if the transaction is just taking too long time. The higher you set the threshold, the lower the risk of catching anything that is not an infinte loop.) Then I guess you could use Aspect-Oriented Programming (AOP) to wrap this exception and create a notification.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is unsolvable problem see the [Halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). Of course, you can set some timeout or set some "command counter" but then, there is a new problem with horizon (what if the program stops after `timeout + 1` seconds?)